# Partial Derivative of Sigmoid

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, machine-learning

As it has been stated elsewhere, the derivative of sigmoid is $\sigma$(x)(1-$\sigma$(x)). So with that being said I just would like for verification that when taking the partial derivative to a sigmoid function that I am correct in my thinking.  So lets say we had a function f(x) = $\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$) and the goal is to take the partial derivative of f(x) with respect to $w_1$.  We have:

1. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_1}$= $\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$)
2. Based off the knowledge of what the derivative of sigmoid is, can we rewrite the problem as?$$\\$$ $\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$)(1-$\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$))$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_1}($$w_1$x + $b_1$)
3. If so, then proceeding on: $\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$)(1-$\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$))(1*x + 0)
4. Thus the final answer is: $\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$)(1-$\sigma$($w_1$x + $b_1$))(x)

Is this correct thinking?  Thanks!

Comment: Answer is correct. You only need to use chain rule. Set $y = w_1 x + b_1$ then: $\frac{df}{dw_1} = \frac{df}{dy} \frac{dy}{dw_1}$

Comment: @Saleh Thank you for verifying!

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\p{\partial}\def\s{\sigma}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Define the following vector and matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
W &= w_1 &&b = b_1 \\
y &= Wx+b &\qiq &dy = dW\,x\\
f &= \s(y) &\qiq &F = \Diag f \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential and gradient of $f$
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= \LR{F-F^2} dy \\
 &= \LR{F-F^2} dW\,x \\
 &= \LR{F-F^2}\star x:dW \\
\grad fW
 &= \LR{F-F^2}\star x \\
}$$
where $(\star)$ and $(:)$ denote the dyadic and Frobenius products, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&A:B \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
&\E = F\star x \qiq \E_{ijk} = F_{ij}x_{k}  \\
}$$
Note that $\LR{\grad fW}$ is a vector-by-matrix gradient,
and therefore a $\,3^{rd}$ *order tensor*.

Perhaps it's better to write the gradient in component notation
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f_i}{W_{jk}}
 &= \LR{F_{ij}-F_{ij}^2} x_k \\
}$$